# Why is there an extra number?

Tags: c, date

Example:

input(dd mm yyyy): 11 11 2011

output: 11th November 2011

It's kind of correct but there's an extra number between the month and year

I don't know how to remove it. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getDay(int day)
{
  switch(day)
  {
    case 1: printf("%dst ", day); break;
    case 2: printf("%dnd ", day); break;
    case 3: printf("%drd ", day); break;
    default: printf("%dth ", day); break;
  }
}
int getMonth(int month)
{
  switch(month)
  {  
    case 1: printf("January "); break;
    case 2: printf("February "); break;
    case 3: printf("March "); break;
    case 4: printf("April "); break;
    case 5: printf("May "); break;
    case 6: printf("June "); break;
    case 7: printf("July "); break;
    case 8: printf("August "); break;
    case 9: printf("September "); break;
    case 10: printf("October "); break;
    case 11: printf("November "); break;
    case 12: printf("December "); break;
    default: printf("Invalid "); break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int day, month, year;
  printf("Enter date in dd mm yyyy format: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
  day = getDay(day);
  month = getMonth(month);
  year = year;
  printf("%d", day);
  printf("%d", month);
  printf("%d", year);
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: *"Example input(dd mm yyyy): 11 11 2011 / output: 11th November 2011 / It's kind of correct but there's an extra number between the month and year "* Er, no, "11th November 2011" is correct for "11 11 2011", surely?! I don't see anything extra between "November" and "2011". What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that you're declaring `getDay` and `getMonth` as returning `int` but you're not returning anything from them, so the return value will be whatever was lying around the relevant register (AX on 80x86 systems). If you declare a return type other than `void`, you must use `return n` where `n` is what the function should return. And you should be using compiler flags making it an error when you don't do that, 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @T.J Crowder put it as an answer so i can upvote you =)

Comment: Don't do this: `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `    case 1: case 21: case 31: printf("%dst ", day); break;
    case 2: case 22: printf("%dnd ", day); break;
    case 3: case 23: cprintf("%drd ", day); break;`

Answer (score 1):

Why your `getMonth` function (which IMO should be called `printMonth`) both has a side-effect (it prints something) and gives some useful (but unspecified) value (i.e. there is a missing `return`)? You should learn to enable all warnings, improve your code till no warnings are given by the compiler, and to use the debugger. On Linux that means compiling with `gcc -Wall -g source.c -o myprog` then debugging with `gdb myprog`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getMonth()` and `getDay()` functions both should return an `int` according to the headers, you're not returning anything from the functions, so what's stored in these lines:

```
day = getDay(day);
month = getMonth(month);
```

Is anyone's guess, then you're printing those values here:

```
printf("%d", day);   
printf("%d", month);
```

If you just want to display "11th November 2011" have both your `getDay` and `getMonth` functions return void, don't re-assign `day` and `month`, and restructure your output:

```
getDay(day);         //print day and "th" or "st" or "rd"
getMonth(month);     //print month
printf("%d", year);  //print year
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Solved it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you were printing day and month twice here is redefined code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void getDay(int day)
 {
   switch(day)
 {
      case 1: printf("%dst ", day); break;
       case 2: printf("%dnd ", day); break;
       case 3: printf("%drd ", day); break;
       default: printf("%dth ", day); break;
 }
}
void getMonth(int month)
{
 switch(month)
{
  case 1: printf("January "); break;
   case 2: printf("February "); break;
   case 3: printf("March "); break;
    case 4: printf("April "); break;
case 5: printf("May "); break;
case 6: printf("June "); break;
case 7: printf("July "); break;
case 8: printf("August "); break;
case 9: printf("September "); break;
case 10: printf("October "); break;
case 11: printf("November "); break;
case 12: printf("December "); break;
default: printf("Invalid "); break;
}
}

int main()
{
   int day, month, year;
   printf("Enter date in dd mm yyyy format: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
      getDay(day);
    getMonth(month);
    year;
   // printf("%d", day);
  // printf("%d", month);
   printf("%d", year);
   fflush(stdin);
   getchar();
}
```

this is one way....

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getDay(int day)
{
  switch(day)
  {
    case 1: printf("%dst ", day); break;
    case 2: printf("%dnd ", day); break;
    case 3: printf("%drd ", day); break;
    default: printf("%dth ", day); break;
  }
}
int getMonth(int month)
{
  switch(month)
  {  
    case 1: printf("January "); break;
    case 2: printf("February "); break;
    case 3: printf("March "); break;
    case 4: printf("April "); break;
    case 5: printf("May "); break;
    case 6: printf("June "); break;
    case 7: printf("July "); break;
    case 8: printf("August "); break;
    case 9: printf("September "); break;
    case 10: printf("October "); break;
    case 11: printf("November "); break;
    case 12: printf("December "); break;
    default: printf("Invalid "); break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int day, month, year;
  printf("Enter date in dd mm yyyy format: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
  getDay(day);
  getMonth(month);
  printf("%d", year);
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of bugs and undefined behavior in that code. I would suggest doing something similar to this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
  DAY_FORMAT_ST,
  DAY_FORMAT_ND,
  DAY_FORMAT_RD,
  DAY_FORMAT_TH,
  DAY_FORMAT_N

} day_format_t;

#define MONTHS_N  12


const char* get_day_str   (unsigned int day);
const char* get_month_str (unsigned int month);



int main()
{
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;

  printf("Enter date in dd mm yyyy format: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
  getchar(); // clear trailing line feed from stdin


  printf("%d%s ", day, get_day_str(day));
  printf("%s ", get_month_str(month));
  printf("%d", year);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}



const char* get_day_str (unsigned int day)
{
  static const char* DAY_FORMAT [DAY_FORMAT_N] =
  {
    "st",
    "nd",
    "rd",
    "th"
  };

  day_format_t  day_index = day - 1; // compensate for 0-index arrays
  const char*   result;

  if (day_index < DAY_FORMAT_TH)
  {
    result = DAY_FORMAT[day_index];
  }
  else
  {
    result = DAY_FORMAT[DAY_FORMAT_TH];
  }

  return result;
}

const char* get_month_str (unsigned int month)
{
  static const char* MONTH [MONTHS_N] =
  {
    "January",
    "February",    
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  };

  return MONTH [month-1];
}
```

Please note that the code needs additional error handling to handle weird user inputs, and that such error handling should preferably be in main() and not inside the functions.